standalone.cls maximum tikz picture size is 575?
I am trying to create an eps/pdf includeable graphics, and rather than working with fractions, I thought I would simply use large integers.  However, somehow the standalone class and tikz don't like to go above 575:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] at (0,0) {lt};  %% picture dimensions
\node[draw] at (575,575) {rb}; %% add one, and we die
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}

is it easy to tell standalone tikz to be more generous?

'Don't like' in what sense? Do you get an error? Which? Your example compiles fine here. If you're asking about an error, provide code which produces the error and include the text of the error message. Yes, it is easy to tell tikz to be more generous. Unfortunately, this is not a tikz error but a TeX one. No, it is not easy (or, even, difficult) to tell TeX to be more generous. You simply have to avoid exceeding TeX's maximum dimension.

You can easily make 576 smaller, though ;).

Check out \pgfmathparse{\maxdimen/1cm}\pgfmathresult

This is not a TikZ error but a TeX one. You've exceeded TeX's maximum dimension. It is not possible to persuade TeX to exceed that dimension in the strong sense that it would no longer be TeX. This is a hard limit and TeX is frozen (except for bug fixes).
However, it is very easy to make 576 smaller. Just change TikZ's unit size.
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
\node[draw] at (0,0) {lt};  %% picture dimensions
\node[draw] at (576,576) {rb}; %% add one, and we die
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}

[Even if Okular didn't have a bug which renders my images terrible, an image of an empty, undrawn box would hardly merit posting. Imagine a white area 576mm by 576mm. This one is easy to do in your head!]

it's a bug!  ;-)

@ivoWelch But whose?
